# how to add class inside checkbox and label field

Tags: yii

i want to implement this html code into yii format.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox1" onclick="" id=""/>
<label class="gender" for="" id="">Female</label>
```

i tried to implement this code.

```
$form->checkBox($model,'gender',array('class'=>'gen'),array('template'=>'{label}')
```

but i don't know how to assign **gender** css class to label field? could please suggest me how to implement above html code in right way.

Comment: you can put this with JQuery, because i think that 'CHtml::checkBox' does not allow to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer this [Different Checkbox Properties](http://www.bsourcecode.com/2013/03/yii-chtml-checkboxlist.html). you will get answer from there...

**if you want to use Chtml::checkBox...**

```
<?php
  echo CHtml::checkBox('gender', 
  array(''),array('class'=>'checkbox1')); ?>

 <label style="width:150px;"class="gender">
    <?php echo 'Gender' ;?> 
 </label>
```

**if you want to use $form->checkBox...**

```
<?php
 echo $form->checkBox($model,'gender', array('class'=>'checkbox1'));                                               
?>
 <label style="width:150px;"class="gender">
    <?php echo 'Gender';?> 
 </label>
```

Try it's working i have tried in my form...

Comment: But when you go to 'edit' view, this checkBox will not be marked.. And with this code you have 2 labels. '<label>' and the '$form->labelEx()'

Comment: ok @Coder but you've a mistake now on: "echo echo 'Gender';" spare a 'echo'. ;)

Comment: @DanielVaquero Again sorry :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** 
I do this:

```
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model, 'gender', array('class'=>'checkbox1')); ?>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'gender', array('class'=>'genger')); ?>
```

Comment: how to asssign class to the label part?

Comment: @DanielVaquero you are using CHtml::checkboxlist then no need to pass $model.. it will generate error.. Please make it correct

Comment: I've done tests on a view without form... now I'll change it. sorry

Comment: This method is design to make a **list** of checkboxes. If you would look into its source, you would see that it creates input, label etc and renders them. But in meanwhile it does much more, which you don't want here. Not god for performance if you develop that way every single html tag, by the way, in more lines of (well formated) code.

Comment: detail the problem, please

Answer (score 0):

`CHtml::checkBox()` gives you only the input tag
To create a `<label>` you should use `CHtml::label()` method. There you can set class property for this tag.

Comment: tnx buddy for helping me... got answer from Coder.

Answer (score 0):

You just can add `labelOptions` array value to control label:

```
echo $form->checkBoxList(
  $model,
  'attr',
  array('ggg','hhh'),
  'htmlOptions' => array(
    'labelOptions' => array(
      //put here what you want
    )
  )
);
```